# Converting DataSnapshot to custom struct object - Swift 4

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

So, In my project I've created a custom struct:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

struct CheckedIn {

    let ref: DatabaseReference?
    let key: String
    let max_cm: String
    let max_in: String
    let weight_kg: Int
    let weight_lb: Int

    init(key: String = "", max_cm: String, max_in: String, weight_kg: Int, weight_lb: Int) {

        self.ref = nil
        self.key = key
        self.max_cm = max_cm
        self.max_in = max_in
        self.weight_kg = weight_kg
        self.weight_lb = weight_lb

    }

    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        guard
            let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject],
            let max_cm = value["checked_max_cm"] as? String,
            let max_in = value["checked_max_in"] as? String,
            let weight_kg = value["checked_weight_kg"] as? Int,
            let weight_lb = value["checked_weight_in"] as? Int
        else {
            return nil
        }

        self.ref = snapshot.ref as DatabaseReference
        self.key = snapshot.key
        self.max_cm = max_cm
        self.max_in = max_in
        self.weight_kg = weight_kg
        self.weight_lb = weight_lb

    }

    func toAnyObject() -> Any {

        return [

            "checked_max_cm": self.max_cm,
            "checked_max_in": self.max_in,
            "checked_weight_kg": self.weight_kg,
            "checked_weight_in": self.weight_lb

        ]
    }
}
```

This is the structure of my database:

[image]

And I'm trying to retrieve some data in a view controller using the following code:

```
ref.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

    var newItems: [CheckedIn] = []

    for child in snapshot.children {

        print(child)

        if let snapshot = child as? DataSnapshot, let company = CheckedIn(snapshot: snapshot) {

            newItems.append(company)

        }

    }

    print(newItems)
    self.companiesCheckedIn = newItems
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: sv)

}
```

The problem is that, whenever I try to open the view controller (this chunk of code is inside the .viewDidLoad), the list 'newItems' is empty. The strange thing is that when I try to run

> print(child)

all of the data is printed,

[image]

So I assume that the 'if let snapshot = child as? DataSnapshot, let company = CarryOn(snapshot: snapshot)' block is not running, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem using a workaround:

This code goes before the `viewDidLoad()` method of your ViewController

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("alldata")
var companyName: [String] = []
var maxCm: [String] = []
var maxIn: [String] = []
var weightKg: [Int] = []
var weightLb: [Int] = []
```

And in the `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref.queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String:[String:AnyObject]]
        let sorted = snapshotValue.sorted() { $0.key.lowercased() < $1.key.lowercased() }

        for (key, _) in sorted {

            let keys = snapshotValue[key]
            let company_name = key
            self.companyName.append(company_name)
            let carry_max_cm = keys?["keyname"] as! String
            self.maxCm.append(carry_max_cm)
            let carry_max_in = keys?["keyname"] as! String
            self.maxIn.append(carry_max_in)
            let carry_weight_kg = keys?["keyname"] as! Int
            self.weightKg.append(carry_weight_kg)
            let carry_weight_lb = keys?["keyname"] as! Int
            self.weightLb.append(carry_weight_lb)

        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

`let sorted = snapshotValue.sorted() { $0.key.lowercased() < $1.key.lowercased() }`

Orders the dictionary alphabetically

Answer (score -2):

your "checked_weight_kg" & "checked_weight_in" is a integer type but you assign String type.

your code ->

```
let weight_kg = value["checked_weight_kg"] as? String,
let weight_lb = value["checked_weight_in"] as? String
```

to Change ->

```
init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        guard
            let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject],
            let max_cm = value["carry_max_cm"] as? String,
            let max_in = value["carry_max_in"] as? String,
            let weight_kg = value["checked_weight_kg"] as? Int,
            let weight_lb = value["checked_weight_in"] as? Int
            else {
                return nil
        }

        self.ref = snapshot.ref as DatabaseReference
        self.key = snapshot.key
        self.max_cm = max_cm
        self.max_in = max_in
        self.weight_kg = weight_kg
        self.weight_lb = weight_lb

    }
```

Comment: I've tried to change my code as you suggested, but the result is the same as before. I've updated my code in the question @Sabbir Ahmed

Comment: It says ' Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Int' '

Comment: ohh it's ok already you change type string to int so you don't need to cast

Comment: So what do I have to do now? The problem is persisting

Comment: I am trying to fiend this problem when I fiend knock you

Comment: can you conform snapshot.children have data and send me the data

Comment: @edoriggio I think you can't perfectly implement firebase data response call please check this url I think help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/42262542/7051513

Comment: I've updated the question by adding a photo of the data. The problem is that now all those snapshots in stuct objects.

Comment: your response all Int type data but stile now your let max_cm: String
    let max_in: String so please change also String to Int

Comment: I can't do this because in my code I use the .split method which can only be used with strings, not Int

Comment: 55x40x24, 55x40x20 etc. are not Int, so I cannot cast them as Int

Comment: hoo your using wrong key (checked_max_cm ->  carry_max_cm), update my answer please check